# Java code making error

Tags: java

I am trying to run the following java codes to make it look like this [image]

But I am having problem I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have three class testFacebook, Facebookperson, and facebook.

This is my code

```
public class testFacebook{

  // This is the testFacebook class

  public static void main (String[] argc){
      System.out.println();
      FacebookPerson p1 = new FacebookPerson("John");
      System.out.println(p1.getName()+ "' mood is "+ p1.getMood() +".");
      System.out.println(p1.getName()+ "' facebook content is "+ p1.getFacebookContent() +".");

      p1.setMood("happy");
      System.out.println(p1.getName()+ "' mood is "+ p1.getMood() +".");
      System.out.println(p1.getName()+ "' facebook content is "+ p1.getFacebookContent() +".");

      p1.setMood("sad");
      System.out.println(p1.getName()+ "' mood is "+ p1.getMood() +".");
      System.out.println(p1.getName()+ "' facebook content is "+ p1.getFacebookContent() +".");
  }

}


public class FacebookPerson{

  // This is the FacebookPerson class
  private String myname;
  private String mood;
  private Facebook fb;

  public FacebookPerson(String name){
      myname = name;
      mood ="initial mood";
      fb = new Facebook();
  }

  public void setMood(String newMood){
     mood = newMood;
     fb.setContent(mood);
  }

  public String getMood(){
      return mood;
  }
  public String getFacebookContent(){
     return content;
  }
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

}

public class Facebook{

   // This is the Facebook class

   private String content;

   public void setContent(String newContent){
    content = newContent+"_content";
   }

   public Facebook(){
    content = "initial_content";
   }



}
```

But I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: and what is your actual output?

Comment: Could you tell us what is the error? :\

Comment: It say I have an error somehow

Comment: where is `getFacebookContent()` defined?

Comment: Maan... That compiler is troubling you.

Comment: You also did not create `getName()` method in `FacebookPerson` class.

Comment: Let me see getFacebookContent hmm I should make make it in the java class I should make it public string getFacebookcontent(){ return content;}

Comment: Ok I will make one but would I make it like this

Comment: public string getFacebookcontent(){ return content;}  something like that

Comment: "It say I have an error somehow" - No, the compiler doesn't tell you "you have an error somehow". Read the error message. It tells you exactly what the error is and where in your source code it is. Copy and paste that error message here, if you don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

1. Update the `getFacebookContent()` method in `FacebookPerson` to return the content using `fb` object as below.

   ```
    public String getFacebookContent(){
        return fb.getContent();
     }
   ```
2. Implement `getContent()` method in `Facebook` as below:

   ```
    public String getContent(){
        return content;
     }
   ```

In addition, you may want to initialize `content` variable as `Initial_Content` instead of `null` as you are expecting in the output.

Comment: Hmm I tried that and it still will not compile I am not sure what else could be wrong.

Comment: Actually I see now gracias

Answer (score 2):

Thats where the problem is :

```
public FacebookPerson(String name){
  myname = name;
  mood ="initial mood";
  fb = new Facebook();
```

}

For initial mood, the constructor of `Facebook` sets the content to "null". It should be set to initial_content.

```
public Facebook(){
content = "null";
```

}

Comment: That is the least of his problem.

Comment: So It should work If I add getFacebookContent acessor

Comment: well,that should help you get rid of some your compilation problems atleast..

Comment: Hmm It is still not functioning for some reasonn

Comment: Along with what csn said you also need to modify getFacebookContent method to reference the fb property

Comment: where is getName() defined?

Comment: I have now defined getName()